Powerapps text or number predicted in gallery
i have a gallery in PowerApp but in my label i get everytime the fault that a text or number is predicted.
looks like this:
ThisItem.Name

The items in my gallery are comming from a collection and my collection is lookin like that:
Collect(colOdA; {Name: tbl_OdA.Title; Adress: tbl_OdA.Adress; National: tbl_OdA.National; ...})

I've already tried to write it down in this forms:
Text(ThisItem.Name)

Value(ThisItem.Name)

ThisItem.Name.Text

ThisItem.Name.Value


Assuming that tbl_OdA is a table (such as a collection or a data source), then the type of tbl_OdA.Title, tbl_OdA.Adress, ... are also tables (with a single column Title, Adress, ..., respectively).
If you want to collect specific columns from tbl_OdA into the collection colOdA, then you can use one of the following:
Collect(colOdA, ShowColumns(tbl_OdA, Title, Adress, National, ...))

or if you want to be more explicit about the schema, or update some values, you can use the ForAll function:
Collect(
    colOdA,
    ForAll(
        tbl_OdA,
        {
            Title: ThisRecord.Title,
            Adress: ThisRecord.Adress,
            National: ThisRecord.National,
            ...
            AnotherField: <expression that doesn't need to come from tbl_Od>
        }
    )
)

